How do I find the right AI tool
Is there a portal that can help me look up the right AI tool for a task? For example, if I am looking for a image editor that can accept natural lang commands (like “remove the silver pole in the background”) or if I am looking for an AI tool that can help me chat with my web site content (like I provide a link and can ask questions off of entire content of the web site including linked in-links), where do I search for such tools?
LLMs like GPT-4, Claude,. give fair answers when asked for AI tools for a specific task but not deep enough. If there is a dedicated aggregator that aggregates all AI tools, that’d be quite amazing and helpful.


If there is a dedicated aggregator that aggregates all AI tools, that’d be quite amazing and helpful.

Here is one list: https://github.com/steven2358/awesome-generative-ai
And here is a long list of AI agents: https://github.com/e2b-dev/awesome-ai-agents
